# dapper nuget 1.7 enums mapping

Tags: c#, mysql, enums, dapper

I've encountered an issue after I upgraded to the latest version of Dapper from Nuget (v 1.7).

It always return the first enums member (that is, it fail to maps).

I am using MySQL as the database.

```
CREATE TABLE `users_roles` (
    `userId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `roleId` INT(11) NOT NULL,  
    KEY `user_id` (`userId`),
    KEY `role_id` (`roleId`)
);

INSERT INTO `users_roles` (`userId`, `roleId`) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO `users_roles` (`userId`, `roleId`) VALUES (2, 2);

public enum Role { 
  Anonymous = 0, Authenticate = 1, Administrator = 2
}

var role = Current.Db.Query<Role>(@"SELECT roleId as Role FROM users_roles
    WHERE userId=@id", new { id = 2 }).FirstOrDefault();
```

It gives the expected output in Dapper nuget v1.6.  Is this the correct behavior for the new version (1.7)?

**Update:**

After doing some testing with a few console application and fresh mvc3 appications I found that the behavior of Dapper enum mapping is inconsistent when you map the enum type directly.

However, mapping an enum as a property of a class somehow consistently returns the correct map

```
public class User
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Role Role { get; set; }
}

var user = Current.Db.Query<User>(@"SELECT roleId as Role, userId as Id 
    FROM users_roles
    WHERE userId=@id", new { id = 2 }).FirstOrDefault();
```

the result of user.Role somehow returns the expected output

Comment: Looks like a bug; please log it on the project site

Comment: thank you, log it already... waiting for response

Comment: This has been fixed *in the code* since May 10th. We haven't re-deployed Nuget, AFAIK, though.

Answer (score 1):

Until the bug is fixed my workaround is to modify GetDeserializer method with extra condition

> || type.IsEnum

to use struct deserializer for enums as follows:

```
        private static Func<IDataReader, object> GetDeserializer(Type type, IDataReader reader, int startBound, int length, bool returnNullIfFirstMissing)
        {
...
            if (!(typeMap.ContainsKey(type) || type.IsEnum /* workaround! */ || type.FullName == LinqBinary))
            {
                return GetTypeDeserializer(type, reader, startBound, length, returnNullIfFirstMissing);
            }
            return GetStructDeserializer(type, startBound);

        }
```